# Where to Check Internet Connection frequently in OSX application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I would required to implement the OSX application online/offline mode.

When internet is available the app icon should online([image]) otherwise the icon should change to offline([image]).

I have implemented checking the internet connection availability(Refered Reachability sample code) but i don't have idea about how to implement online/offline mode like continuously checking the internet connection and update the icons.

Please guide how to achieve the functionality.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: When you use the Apple Reachability you already get notified when the internet connection goes offline and comes back online. So why do want to it continuously? Just check your icon when you receive connection offline message from Reachability. Reachability is already checking the connection state for you, you don't have to do it your self.

Comment: @NicolòMonili It's not duplicate . . Please read my question. . I have implemented to find the internet connection offline/online.. I would like to check to implement the functionality frequently update the online/offline status in icon . . Where i have to implement ? App delegate or NSthread ?

Comment: @rckoenes  If app is run on the Menu bar and the internet connection is not available .. How to trigger the application and update the status icon online/offline mode ? Shall i use NSNotificationCenter ?